# Loosing precision in decimal after joining dfs

Tags: python, pyspark, decimal, precision

I've met an issue. I import a csv and use it as df, just after importing I see vaules such as 0,000001,then I join several dfs and loose the ending "1". It's not the case of not printing out because then I'm trying the (x/sum(x)).overWindow(partitionBy()) and it gives null. How to preserve the original value?
Importing csv:
[Importing csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8zPA.png)
Visible value (I added "1" just to make te ".0000001" visible):
[Visible value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulWQ3.png)
join and filter after join:
[join and filter after join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYm3Y.png)
and the result: [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE8H0.png)

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code?
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: please post an example CSV or DF and code that you use which throws the error:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example